# Show div after 2 seconds of page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to show a div 2 seconds after the page is loaded. I can successfully do the reverse by hiding the div two seconds after the page loads. The issue is that nothing occurs and the div stays hidden. How can I properly show a div after two seconds of page load? Extra: mean while the two seconds are running show an ajax loading gif and then fade in the div

```
<script type = "text/javascript">  
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#contentPost").show('fadeIn', {}, 500)
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

**html/css**

```
<style>
.contentPost { display:none;}
</style>

<div class="contentPost">
 <h2>Hi there</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your HTML-  How are you making it hidden to begin with?

Comment: @SteveH. I have added the html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".contentPost").delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Will work perfectly.

Comment: That's nice jQuery elegance.

Comment: @Mooseman Still not showing anything. I updated my question with the HTML. I am actually hidding the div with css `display:none;`

Comment: `.fadeIn(500);` will override `display: none`. I just noticed that your HTML uses a classname, and not an ID. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

Ive never seen your show method written like that. Try altering it into use the jquery method [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/):

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#contentPost").delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
});
</script>
```

The [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method does not accept any arguments and won't work as you want it to.

Comment: Still not showing anything. I updated my question with the HTML. I am actually hidding the div with css `display:none;`.

Comment: @Undefined show() *can* take options, according to the jQuery 1.0 docs page (https://api.jquery.com/show/).