# How to focus a div automatically on page load

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this code....

```
  <div id="details">
                    <nav>
                            <a href="#1"><span>Summary</span></a>
                            <a href="#2"><span>Personal</span></a>
                    </nav>
                </div>

        <div id="1" class="navLinks"> <?php include 'includes/i_includes/summary.php';?> </div>
        <div id="2" class="navLinks"> <?php include 'includes/i_includes/info.php';?> </div>
```

and then I also have this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('nav a').click(function() {

          $('.navLinks').hide();
          $(this.getAttribute('href')).show()
        });


        </script>
```

I would like to make so on page load... the content of Summary is automatically shown..

Comment: use  window.location.hash = '#details';

Answer (score 3):

you can use `.filter().click()`

```
$('nav a').click(function() {
     $('.navLinks').hide();
     $(this.getAttribute('href')).show()
}).filter('[href="#1"]').click();
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/0gmz6o77/)

or you can use `.eq().click();`

```
$('nav a').click(function() {
    $('.navLinks').hide();
    $(this.getAttribute('href')).show()
}).eq(0).click();
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/0gmz6o77/1/)

Comment: First one is working now with the HREF added in. Thanks.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 glad it helped .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this sricpt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#yourdivid").show();
 });
```

Check on Following Links:

[Show div after 2 seconds of page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636362/show-div-after-2-seconds-of-page-load)

[Hide div with specific class while page is loading then show again after load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945002/hide-div-with-specific-class-while-page-is-loading-then-show-again-after-load)